# Creating POJO and returning multiple object values

Tags: java, json, list, object, pojo

I am reading from a JSON of the format :

```
{
 "student" : [ 
  {
   "roll" : 1, 
   "name" : "abc",
   "subjects" : [
     {
      "major" : "chemistry", 
      "minor" : "maths"
     }, 
     {
      "major" : "biology", 
      "minor" : "physics" 
     } 
   ]
  }, 
  {
   "roll" : 2, 
   "name" : "xyz", 
   "subjects" : [
     {
      "major" : "english", 
      "minor" : "biology"
     }, 
     {
      "major" : "english", 
      "minor" : "physics" 
     }
   ]
  } 
 ]
}
```

I am storing "student" to a string and making each student details - 'roll, name, subjects' into a POJO.

1. ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(); 
   Map<String, List object = mapper.readValue(Json, ?);

   When I give 'Map.class', I get error and when I give new TypeReference<Map<String,List>>(){}, it stores the package, not json to POJO. What do I give in place of '?'
2. What is the best way to return all the major and minor of a particular student given the student name? Should I do a hashmap or list? Or is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that you are reading JSON string, and you need to convert them into POJO, in that case you need to design you POJO as below,

```
class Reports{
    
    private final List<Student> student;

   // getters & setters

}

class Student {

private final int roll;
private final String name;
private final List<Subject> subjects;

// getters & setters

}


class Subject{ 

private final String major;
private final String minor;

// getters & setters

}
```

Then you can use as below,

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Reports reports = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Reports.class);
```

**POST Edited**

Comment: Since "student" is not included in POJO, it gives the error Unrecognized field "student"